Text not rendering in OpenGL
I'm trying to get some text on screen with the freetype library in OpenGL. But it's just not being rendered for some reason, here's the code for it:
void RenderText()
{
    textShader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(textVAO);

    const std::string& text = "Hello";
    const std::string& fontPath = "newfont.ttf";
    float              startX = 750.0f;
    float              y = 800.0f;
    glm::vec2          scale = glm::vec2(100.0f, 100.0f); // Scaling factors for x and y

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, screenWidth, 0.0f, screenHeight);

    textShader.setVec4("textColor", glm::vec4(1.0f));
    textShader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    for (auto c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); ++c)
    {
        Character ch = fonts[fontPath][*c];

        float xpos = startX + ch.Bearing.x * scale.x;          // Apply x scaling
        float ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale.y; // Apply y scaling

        float w = ch.Size.x * scale.x; // Apply x scaling
        float h = ch.Size.y * scale.y; // Apply y scaling
        float vertices[6][4] = {{xpos, ypos + h, 0.0f, 0.0f},    {xpos, ypos, 0.0f, 1.0f},
                                {xpos + w, ypos, 1.0f, 1.0f},

                                {xpos, ypos + h, 0.0f, 0.0f},    {xpos + w, ypos, 1.0f, 1.0f},
                                {xpos + w, ypos + h, 1.0f, 0.0f}};
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textVBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        startX += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale.x; // Move to the next character position 
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

The 'fonts' map is correctly loaded in.
I debugged the rendering in RenderDoc and found that draw calls were present and the glyph textures were being binded, but they just weren't being rendered to the screen.
Here's the shaders:
// VERTEX SHADER
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>
out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}


// FRAGMENT SHADER
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec4 textColor;

void main()
{    
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    FragColor = textColor * sampled;
}

And the font loading function:
void LoadFont(const std::string& fontPath)
{
    if (fonts.find(fontPath) != fonts.end())
    {
        // Font already loaded
        return;
    }
 
    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontPath.c_str(), 0, &face))
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
 
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
 
    std::map<char, Character> characters;
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
                     0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
 
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 
        Character character = {texture,
                               glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
                               glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
                               static_cast<GLuint>(face->glyph->advance.x)};
 
        characters.insert(std::pair<char, Character>(c, character));
    }
    fonts.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::map<char, Character>>(fontPath, characters));
 
    FT_Done_Face(face);
}


Blending?
